# Supertest: check for something that happened after res.send()

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, restify, supertest

I'm doing a POST to create an item and send the newly created item as response back to the client.

```
async (req, res, next) => {
  const item = await createItem(xx, yy, zz);
  res.send(201, item);
}
```

Now I also want to send out notifications after creating an item **but also after responding to the client** - to make the request as fast as possible.

```
async (req, res, next) => {
  const item = await createItem(xx, yy, zz);
  res.send(201, item);

  sendNotification(item);
}
```

If I want to test this using jest + supertest, this is how it'd look:

```
test('return 201', () => {
  const app = require('./');
  return request(app)
    .post('/api/items')
    .send({})
    .expect(201)
    .then(response => {
      // test something more
    });
}
```

But how could I test if the `sendNotification()` was called?

Comment: Does `sendNotification()` use `res`? That wouldn't work. Basically, `send` ends HTTP response.  Although you could reach code after `res.send`, any reference to `res` will be unsuccessful. What does `sendNotification` do?

Comment: @PruthviKumar it sends out push notifications and is not using `res`.

Comment: Well, in that case, you could use `.done(() => {//test something set/used by sendnotification})` to validate if `sendNotification` was invoked.

Comment: @PruthviKumar that isn't working because it's not benn called yet at that point

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not perfect but working right now:

I added a call to an external method from another package at the end of the async request-handler. I know that you shouldn't add code just for testing purposes but I prefered this to random `setTimeouts` in my tests.

**hooks.js**

```
const deferreds = [];

exports.hookIntoEnd = () => {
  const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deferreds.push({ resolve, reject });
  });
  return p;
};

exports.triggerEndHook = () => {
  if (Array.isArray(deferreds)) {
    deferreds.forEach(d => d.resolve());
  }
};
```

**handler.js**

```
const { triggerEndHook } = require('./hooks');

async (req, res, next) => {
  const item = await createItem(xx, yy, zz);
  res.send(201, item);

  sendNotification(item);

  // this is only here so that we can hook into here from our tests
  triggerEndHook();
}
```

**test.js**

```
test('run + test stuff after res.send', async () => {
  const server = require('../index');
  const { hookIntoEnd } = require('../hooks');
  const aws = require('../utils/aws');

  const getObjectMetadataSpy = jest
    .spyOn(aws, 'getObjectMetadata')
    .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ Metadata: { a: 'b' } }));

  const p = hookIntoEnd();

  const response = await request(server)
    .post('/api/items')
    .send({ foo: 'bar' })
    .set('Accept', 'application/json')
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    .expect(201);

  expect(response.body).toEqual({ id: 1, name: 'test item'});

  // test for code that was run after res.send
  return p.then(async () => {
    console.log('>>>>>>>>>>> triggerEndHook');
    expect(getObjectMetadataSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });
});
```

Comment: @lmoglia that's what I'm using now - not perfect but does the job

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) in Jest to spy on the `sendNotification()` function and assert that it has been called. A simple example:

```
const sendNotification = require('./sendNotification');
const sendNotificationSpy = jest.spyOn(sendNotification);

test('return 201', () => {
  const app = require('./');
  return request(app)
    .post('/api/items')
    .send({})
    .expect(201)
    .then(response => {
      // test something more
      expect(sendNotificationSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
}
```

Comment: this is what I tried but isn't working because `then()` is called before `sendNotification()` was triggered

Comment: Oh, I see. Is `sendNotification` asynchronous? Is there a reason you are not calling it before `res.send()` ?

Comment: I want to respond to the request as fast as possible ... and do some other task that is kind of optional after the response. could be sync or async, doesn't really matter. it's more about how to test this with supertest

Comment: Hi @pkyeck ! Did you find some way to do that? I'm trying to do the same! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After res.send() is called the program calls ***someService.method({param1})*** function.

Using sinon to spy that service method:

```
it('test after send', function(done){
  const spy = sinon.spy(someService, 'method');
  agent
    .set('Authorization', token)
    .post('/foo')
    .expect(200)
    .then(() => {
      return setTimeout(function() {
        // Assert the method was called once
        sinon.assert.callCount(spy, 1);
        // Assert the method was called with '{param1}' parameter
        sinon.assert.calledWith(spy, {param1});
        // Test callback!
        done();
      }, 100);
    });
});
```

- Using *setTimeout* with the minimus time (ms) as possible to wait for the method to be called.

Recommendations and improvements will be appreciated! (I'm still trying to avoid using arbitrary amount of timeout)